# How to Measure Electric-Field Probe Sensitivity?

Tags: electric-fields, units, measurements, sensor

I am doing some reading on current methods for detecting electric fields. A figure of merit for the systems is, naturally, the minimum strength of field that can be measured, in units of Volts per length. But another figure of merit that keeps cropping up is the sensitivity, in units $\text{V}/\text{cm}\cdot\sqrt{\text{Hz}}$.  I am having trouble understanding what these units are, or what this sensitivity is. What is this quantity for electric field probes, how is it measured, and why are these the units?